# Cellular cochains, Hatcher Theorem 3.5, not sure how they use induction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've attached the entire proof for context. I am unsure how to use induction $n$ to obtain that $H^k(X^n;G)=0$ if $k>n$. The isomorphism from the long exact sequence are clear to me. Are we doing induction on the dimension of the cell complex, are we inducting on the degree of to cohomology for a fixed $CW$-complex?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it just use $H^k(X^n;G)\simeq H^k(X^{n-1};G)\simeq\dots\simeq H^k(X^0;G)=0$?

Comment: is it obvious that $H^k(X^0;G)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that statement is meant to be obvious. If $p$ is a one-point space, then $H^k(p;G) = 0$ if $k > 0$. Since $X^0$ is a disjoint union of one-point spaces it follows that $H^k(X^0;G)=0$ for $k>0$ as well (in degree $0$ it will be one copy of $G$ for each $0$-cell in $X^0$).

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, I was thinking that $X$ was a relative CW-complex and could have had a non trivial base space. Thanks @William !